# Unflatten a dot-separated key/value pair into a nested object using Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

The Ramda cookbook explains [here](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook#flatten-a-nested-object-into-dot-separated-key--value-pairs) how to convert a nested object into dot-separated flattened object. 
I'm new to Ramda and I would like to learn how to do the reverse of the above.

It would convert this object:

```
{
  "company.name": "Name is required",
  "solarSystemInfo.name": "Name is required",
  "installer.business.name": "slkdfj is required"
}
```

to,

```
{
  "company": {
    "name": "Name is required"
  },
  "solarSystemInfo": {
    "name": "Name is required"
  },
  "installer": {
    "business": {
      "name": "slkdfj is requried"
    }
  }
}
```

A working fiddle using plain JS is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/remus/tfjH3/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by splitting the object into pairs using [`R.toPairs`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#toPairs), then "unflattening" each pair into an object by splitting the key on each `.` into a list and passing that as the path to [`R.assocPath`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#assocPath) to build out the object. This will result in a list of objects that can then be merged together using [`R.mergeAll`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#mergeAll).

```js
const data = {
  "company.name": "Name is required",
  "solarSystemInfo.name": "Name is required",
  "installer.business.name": "slkdfj is required"
}

const pathPairToObj = (key, val) =>
  R.assocPath(R.split('.', key), val, {})

const unflattenObj = R.pipe(
  R.toPairs,
  R.map(R.apply(pathPairToObj)),
  R.mergeAll
)

console.log(unflattenObj(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Reduce](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduce) you can avoid overwriting of objects with multiple keys.

```js
const data = {
    "company.name": "Name is required",
    "solarSystemInfo.name": "Name is required",
    "installer.business.name": "Reg. name is required",
    "installer.business.code": "NYSE code is required"
}
const buildObj = (acc,value) => {
    [key,val]=value;
    return R.assocPath(R.split('.', key), val, acc);
}

const unflattenObj = R.pipe(
    R.toPairs,
    R.reduce(buildObj,{})
);
console.log(unflattenObj(data));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From "Using Reduce you can avoid overwriting of objects with multiple keys."

If you are on Typescript project and you have "Cannot find key" or "val"... you can use:

```js
const data = {
    "company.name": "Name is required",
    "solarSystemInfo.name": "Name is required",
    "installer.business.name": "Reg. name is required",
    "installer.business.code": "NYSE code is required"
}

const buildObj = (acc, value) => {
  const [key,val] = value
  return R.assocPath(R.split('.', key), val, acc);
}

const unflattenObj = R.pipe(
  R.toPairs,
  R.reduce(buildObj,{})
)

console.log(unflattenObj(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```